# Second embedded Javascript not running in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have two embedded scripts in my HTML files but only the first one runs. The second one doesn't execute, it's just supposed to change the text of the paragraph. I'm really not familiar with javascript and don't know if there's some async wizardry going on. If I remove the jquery include (and change the code to use the plain method of changing elements), it works fine.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="next-track">
            Next Track
        </p>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"/>
    <script>
        $("#next-track").html("Bye JavaScript!");
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: You're missing the `</script>` at the end of the first `<script>`

Comment: You can't combine `<script src=...></script>` into a single `<script src=... />` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the script tag, you cannot close it on the opening.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="next-track">
            Next Track
        </p>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        $("#next-track").html("Bye JavaScript!");
    </script>
</html>
```